# Is there any good alternative to compass-rails for automatic css sprites with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, compass-sass, css-sprites

I installed compass-rails in my Rails 3.2.6 app but only for the automatic sprites feature and I'm thinking that :

1. This is probably overkill
2. I need to launch the watch task or nothing happens (that's not really the problem)
3. Once watch notices changes, it is awfully slow compared to Rails original way

I've tried css_sprite but it won't install because of yet another missing library (I'm on windows)

And lemonade but the server won't start with it in the gemfile since it's been deprecated and integrated into... compass

So I'm wondering if there is any simple gem that can generate sprites and associated classes ?

Comment: I've looked for alternatives too since compass-rails has a bug where it randomly doesn't notice image files changed ... not found anything well maintained so far ... I'm running `rake tmp:clear` and restart the server when I add or edit sprites right now

Comment: I ran into this too although I wasn't running watch at the time, I suppose you do. Thanks for the tip, might save some time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprite Factory has worked well for me for some solutions: https://github.com/jakesgordon/sprite-factory

Comment: Didn't have time to try it yet but it seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Looks interesting. Will be creating a pilot to see if it works out for us.